# How to keep links from opening in new windows with Google Chrome?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, browser

I have a friend who recently switched from PC to a Macbook Air. She's using Google Chrome and telling me that often times when she clicks a link it is opening in a new window, and that behavior seems strange to her because it doesn't happen on the PC.

I know in Google Chrome you can use `Command` to force a link to open in a new tab, but is there sort of the opposite: a way to keep a link from opening in a new tab?

She also mentioned that sometimes when she clicks on dropdown style menus in webpages (generated with the `<select>` element, that they won't actually drop down.

I can't think of any settings that would be causing this strange behavior (I thought about the Chrome preferences and also the trackpad preferences) - but are there any?

Finally, I was looking for a page that had links with some target="_blank" and javascript/new-window examples so I could send it to her to test, but I didn't have any luck.

So in summary:

1) Is there a way on Chrome to force links to open in the current tab?

2) Are there any settings chrome/trackpad/etc that would be causing strange behaviors?

3) Does anyone know of a good test page for testing different types of links?

Comment: Is she using an unstable release channel of Google Chrome?

Comment: What happens with the drop down menus instead? Does nothing happen when they're clicked, does something else happen?

Comment: Latest non beta version of Chrome. Nothing happens at all with them.

Comment: Do you have an publicly accessible example web page where this occurs?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. She's remote and so I haven't had a chance to sit down and go through this with her yet. Was more wondering about general things that could be wrong with her setup rather than trying to debug a single webpage (she says this happens on lots of different pages). I'm going to see if I can do crossloop and get more info and then update the question.

Comment: Sure, it's just that I'd like to see something myself, if possible. You don't have the same issues; I assume you tried to reproduce? One possibility I could think of is some rendering flaw where some elements are overlaid on top of each other, so clicking is intercepted by a different element. I believe objects (e.g. Flash) behave(d) like this.